# How to use WALA for Forward Slicing

Tags: java, program-slicing, wala

I have been working on program slicing for a while. Since that Backward slicing works on a control-flow graph (CFG) and there are plenty of tools that generates CFGs, I easily implemented the Backward slicing algorithm with Java.

However, as read some articles, I have seen that Forward slicing works on system dependence graphs (SDG) and I found that [WALA](http://wala.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) generates SDGs, but also has Forwards Slicing implemented.

WALA is a very big project and I kinda got lost in its codes and documentation. Are there any examples of how I can use [WALA's Forward slicing](http://wala.sourceforge.net/javadocs/trunk/com/ibm/wala/ipa/slicer/Slicer.html) for Java? Or at least how I can generate a given program's SDG in *dot* format so that I can visualize it with Graphviz as well.

Answer (score -2):

[WALA's user guide](http://wala.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/UserGuide:Slicer) may be helpful for you. In its example, you can change the `computeBackwardSlice` method to the `computeForwardSlice` method to achieve a forward slice.

Wala has been implemented be jars, you can go to download the following four jars to invoke their methods.
`com.ibm.wala.core
com.ibm.wala.cast
com.ibm.wala.shrike
com.ibm.wala.util`